# dependency issue at wpa_supplicant service startup

Tags: systemd, udev, systemd-networkd

I have an issue during the bootup sequence of our toradex board (more info [here](https://www.toradex.com/computer-on-modules/colibri-arm-family/nxp-imx-8x)) with wpa_supplicant service failing on "dependency" reason.
I am using pure systemd network setup, with this file for our wifi :

- First for interface renaming :

```
root@colibri:/etc/systemd/network# cat 10-toradex-wifi-ifnames.link
[Match]
Driver=mwifiex_pcie

[Link]
NamePolicy=keep kernel
```

- Second for interface up'ing :

```
root@colibri:/etc/systemd/network# cat 61-wireless-mambo.network
[Match]
Name=mlan0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
IgnoreCarrierLoss=3s

[DHCPv4]
RouteMetric=21
```

- Third for wpa_supplicant (interface specific) :

```
root@colibri:~# cat /etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service 
[Unit]
Description=WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
Requires=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
Before=network.target
Wants=network.target

# NetworkManager users will probably want the dbus version instead.

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-%I.conf -i%I

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
root@colibri:~#
```

I have pinned the issue down to this :

```
root@colibri:~# systemctl status wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service 
○ wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service - WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Nov 03 11:50:02 colibri systemd[1]: Dependency failed for WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
Nov 03 11:50:02 colibri systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service: Job wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

With a bit more details :

```
Nov 03 13:30:41 colibri systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /sys/subsystem/net/devices/mlan0.
Nov 03 13:30:41 colibri systemd[1]: Dependency failed for WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
```

I can tell that i'm reaching a timeout because at startup i have this message when I'm trying to login  :

```
pi@tt:~$ ssh user@192.168.28.38
user@192.168.28.38's password: 
"System is booting up. Unprivileged users are not permitted to log in yet. Please come back later. For technical details, see pam_nologin(8)."
Connection closed by 192.168.28.38 port 22
pi@tt:~$
```

Nothing comes up using `systemd-analyze` or `systemd-analyze` critical-chain or `systemd-analyze blame`.
My guess is that is something related to interface renaming / `udev` and `systemd` race condition, as I can see this :

```
Nov 03 13:30:41 colibri systemd[1]: sys-subsystem-net-devices-mlan0.device: Job sys-subsystem-net-devices-mlan0.device/start failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Check the time : 13:30:41
and then we have this in logs :

```
Nov 03 13:30:43 colibri systemd-networkd[656]: mlan0: udev initialized link
```

It looks like the `udev` initialization is done after `systemd` tries to start the device...

If i let the system reach the timeout, and finally startup, i just have to start the mlan0.service and it works :

```
root@colibri:~# systemctl status wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service 
○ wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service - WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)

Nov 03 13:30:41 colibri systemd[1]: Dependency failed for WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
Nov 03 13:30:41 colibri systemd[1]: wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service: Job wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
root@colibri:~# systemctl start wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service 
root@colibri:~# systemctl status wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service 
● wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service - WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-11-03 13:39:49 UTC; 1s ago
   Main PID: 1333 (wpa_supplicant)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1649)
     Memory: 1.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-wpa_supplicant.slice/wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service
             └─ 1333 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-mlan0.conf -imlan0

Nov 03 13:39:49 colibri systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
Nov 03 13:39:49 colibri wpa_supplicant[1333]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
root@colibri:~# systemctl status wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service 
● wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service - WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version)
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant@.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-11-03 13:39:49 UTC; 5s ago
   Main PID: 1333 (wpa_supplicant)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 1649)
     Memory: 1.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-wpa_supplicant.slice/wpa_supplicant@mlan0.service
             └─ 1333 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant-mlan0.conf -imlan0

Nov 03 13:39:49 colibri systemd[1]: Started WPA supplicant daemon (interface-specific version).
Nov 03 13:39:49 colibri wpa_supplicant[1333]: Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Nov 03 13:39:51 colibri wpa_supplicant[1333]: mlan0: Trying to associate with 00:90:7f:47:66:41 (SSID='<REDACTED>' freq=5220 MHz)
Nov 03 13:39:51 colibri wpa_supplicant[1333]: mlan0: Associated with 00:90:7f:47:66:41
Nov 03 13:39:51 colibri wpa_supplicant[1333]: mlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SUBNET-STATUS-UPDATE status=0
Nov 03 13:39:51 colibri-imx8x-07330229 wpa_supplicant[1333]: mlan0: WPA: Key negotiation completed with 00:90:7f:47:66:41 [PTK=CCMP GTK=CCMP]
Nov 03 13:39:51 colibri wpa_supplicant[1333]: mlan0: CTRL-EVENT-CONNECTED - Connection to 00:90:7f:47:66:41 completed [id=0 id_str=]
root@colibri:~#
```

Any guess ? or tips to create a service file that would fix this ?